# Even if I use flutter Row, the string I want doesn't go to the side

Tags: flutter, dart

Even if I use flutter Row, the string I want doesn't go to the side.
I tried Row and Column and flutter Layouts, but I don't know why the text doesn't move. 
[image]

[image: enter link description here]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Card(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Flexible(
                                flex : 1,
                                 child : Image.network(data[index]['thumbnail'].toString())),
                              Flexible(
                                flex : 2,
                                child : Text(
                                data[index]['title'].toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
                              )),
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the row widgets with `Flexible`:

```dart
Container(
   height: 200, //your desired height
   width: double.infinity,
   child: Row(
           children:<Widget>[
              Flexible(
                  flex: 1, //desired ratio
                  child: yourPhoto(), //replace this with your photo widget
              ),

              Flexible(
                  flex:2, //desired ratio
                  child: Container(
                            height: double.infinity,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: Text("Your Text here"),
                         ),
              ),
]
)
);
```

Comment: I've modified it with what you answered, but I'm making the code and no error. But don't run it.
I reloaded the code above.

Comment: Is there are no error messages? maybe you have a syntax error here or there. recheck your code if possible.

Comment: Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out and Another exception was thrown: 'package: flutter / src / rendering / sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 549 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried various Axis alignments.

Such us:

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[Text("abc")],
         ),
```